# Calling a Python function in loop from C++ runs slow after hours

Tags: python, c++, linux

I am in trouble with a call to a Python function from C++ in a for-loop. The C++ program makes a picture and the Python script converts that into a resized jpeg image.

The snippet of the call from C++:

```cpp
char *antwort;                              
// Python
PyObject *fname, *module, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
Py_Initialize();
PyObject* fname = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"TEST");
PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(fname);
printf("OK -> ");
pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, (char*)"umwandeln");
pArgs = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyUnicode_FromString((char*)filename));
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
auto result = _PyUnicode_AsString(pValue);


antwort = result;                           
Py_DECREF(pFunc);
Py_DECREF(module);
Py_DECREF(fname);
Py_DECREF(pArgs);
Py_DECREF(
Py_Finalize();
```

The Python script:

```py
import sys
import os
import gc
from PIL import Image

def umwandeln(filenam):
    Test = str(filenam)
    Test = Test[2:]
    print ("file : " + Test)
    if Test[-3:] == "tif" or Test[-3:] == "bmp" :
       # print "is tif or bmp"
       outfile = Test[:-3] + "jpeg"
       im = Image.open(Test)
       print ("new filename : " + outfile)
       out = im.convert("RGB")

            
       out.save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=95)
       im.close()
      # print(outfile)
       im2 = Image.open(outfile)
       im2 = im2.resize((300,300),Image.ANTIALIAS)
       im2.save(outfile)
       im2.close()


       os.remove(Test)
       print ("Fertig Script")  
       gc.collect()
       
    
    return outfile
```

The name of the Python file is Test.py.
It runs really good for about 3-4 hours (it runs not suddenly slower step by step). Then I think the `PyImport_Import()` runs slow.

If I start the cpp program again it runs normally, but after a time slower and slower.

The memory usage is about half of the size (3GB from 8).
The CPU usage is about 30%.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you kill the Python environment every time? Why not keep it around between runs? It also looks like your interface to the Python script is "here's a filename, do magic and give me a new filename". Why not just run `python script.py filename filename.out`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem of memory fragmentation over time. Your'e running in the same process the entire time, creating/destructing at least 5 object in every python call (not to mention the probably much higher number in the python functions you are calling within umwandeln()).

You can try to make some of the varibales in umwandeln() static so that they don't need to be allocated/freed every call.

Another approach is to break out the umwandeln() function as a separate python script adding the file name as a script argument. Then you call the script as if it is an external program (which it is) either directly from C++ or using the python subprocess module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). Doing so also means that you can parallellize the image resizing by calling the external script several times for different *filenam*.

This is one of the approaches I'm using for image pre/post processing and I can happily report that I've reach a load factor way above 250 on a 24 cores (Threadripper) Linux PC and it spits out images like there is no tomorrow.

/N